# Best java tool to cache and minify the dojo, jquery js and CSS

Tags: java, javascript, css, caching, minify

The dojo and jquery libraries are downloaded from google CDNS and used in our project. I am looking for a java tool which can cache and minify these tools. The cache should happen inside the ROOT project of tomcat.I know YUI compressor is great minifier  but looking for a open source tool which can do both caching and minify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used grunt js library to minify the JS and CSS in my application. To begin with prepare a gruntexe.js file. Create build.sh file to install and run grunt.

Sample gruntfile.js will as below

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: './src',
                cleanBowerDir: true
            }
        }
    },
    exec: {
        buildUI: {
            command: 'chmod 755 ./build.sh && chmod 755 ./build.sh && ./build.sh'
        }
    },
    replace: {
        replaceHtmlCacheTag: {
            src: ['./*.html', './cache.manifest'],
            dist: ['../'], // Minify all js file in dist folder
            replacements: [{
                    from: /\$\{timestamp\}/g,
                    to: "<%= grunt.template.today('ddmmyyyyhMMss') %>"
                }]
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to minifying and compiling javascript and other web resources (like css) wro4j is probably the most flexible you will find.  I'm not sure if it caches in the way you are talking about but it does have a servlet which can be used from tomcat.

https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [minify JS and CSS](http://jscompress.com/). Minify JS can make 1 JS file merging multiple JS file and same for CSS. so the file caches faster than multiple files.